# How to view logback-android/slf4j file on device?

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview, slf4j, logback

Sup Stack,
I'm trying to debug an app that requires a peripheral to be plugged in to my Droid Turbo's USB port. I decided to use logback-android and slf4j to log to a file on internal storage and then view the log file on a fragment.
Here's the relevant code:
LogFragment.java:

```
/** Displays log file for ElkaUsbTransfer app
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class LogFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "MAIN_LOG_PAGE";

    Logger log_ = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogFragment.class);
    private String page_ = "Main Log";
    StringBuilder log_sb_;
    File f_;

    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        log_sb_ = new StringBuilder(""); // will this reload correctly?
        f_=new File(getActivity().getApplicationContext(
            ).getFilesDir()+File.separator+"elkaUsbTransfer.txt");
        for (String s:getActivity().getApplicationContext().fileList()) {
           log_sb_.append(s+"\n");
        }
        log_.debug("stuff");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_log, container, false);
        TextView logLabel = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.main_log);
        readLog();
        logLabel.setText(log_sb_.toString());
        return rootView;
    }

    protected void readLog() {
        try {
            //Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            //        "logcat -d | grep com.example.agrc.elkausbtransfer | cut -c10-15");
            //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f_));
            String line;
            while((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                log_sb_.append(line+"\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log_sb_.append(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

logback.xml:

```
<configuration>
<appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <!-- Create file appender for a log in the application's data directory -->
    <!--file>/data/data/com.example/files/elkaUsbTransfer.log</file>-->
    <file>/data/data/com.example.agrc.elkausbtransfer/files/elkaUsbTransfer.txt</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="file"/>
</root>
```

How would I view my log file, 'elkaUsbTransfer.txt' in a TextView? I already have the .xml file associated with LogFragment working. Is this a mutex problem associated with viewing my log and writing to my log from the same file?

Comment: Try #adb shell
Or you can access it in Debug mode

Comment: adb shell won't access files on internal storage, not sure what debug mode would do. any other ideas?